# Coolant vs. air fuel ratio or O2 sensor

Tags: coolant, o2-sensor, coolant-leak

If there's a trace of coolant getting into the cylinder combustion chamber what would the effect be on the AFR or O2 sensors fitted to the exhaust pipe?

I'm guessing zirconium sensors would read rich due to less oxygen, but there's likely other factors, just curious.

Comment: Coolant will destroy an O2 sensor if in the exahust stream.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're literally dumping coolant into the intake, i can't imagine you could get enough through the engine to significantly lower the O2 content of the exhaust stream.  The usual causes of coolant through the engine, say a leaking head gasket, generally just adds a small amount with each cycle of the cylinder and that gets mixed with the output from the non-leaking cylinders.  Yes, the coolant can be detected in the exhaust but only by equipment that is designed to detect it.